# Reliability of having arithmetic shift in c++ when targeting x86

Tags: c++, x86

So according to the c++ spec

> The value of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has
>   an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a non-negative value,
>   the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of
>   E1/2^E2. **If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting
>   value is implementation-deﬁned.**

So it's implementation defined, but if I'm using a bug-free compiler targetting x86 platform, and im right shifting using a signed type, is there any reason to doubt I would not shift in signed bits? (x86 supports arithmetic shift obviously)

Comment: Tell me more about this "bug-free compiler" for C++, because I'm honestly yet to see one, even with the biggest compilers like gcc and clang there are differences and bugs every now and then.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I used the term bug-free loosely just to mean a compiler that has some common sense, a modern compiler. intel, gcc, microsoft, etc

Comment: "Implementation-defined" means  that if it works *once* in a certain way for a certain compiler, you can be sure it works the next time as well. (Except for the occasional bug, then, as Benjamin points out.)

Comment: E1 >> E2 is implementation defined _only_ when E1 < 0; I think it is wiser not to right shift on negatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not confuse "implementation defined" with "undefined".  "Implementation defined" means, literally, "the implementation must define it".  It's not random, or even something you should have to determine by experiment.  The behavior is defined by the implementation, and standard-conforming implementations will **document** these behavior details (because to fail to do so is non-conformant in itself).  Barring implementation bugs, programs will faithfully exhibit the behavior defined by their C++ implementation.

Whereas you cannot rely on anything about undefined behavior, you can rely on implementation defined behavior to be consistent within a given C++ implementation.  It is unsafe to assume, however, that different implementations for the same hardware will define these details the same way, or even that different versions of the same implementation will be consistent in that way.